# EF Core 6 & Blazor: Join two tables based on relationship defined in third table

Tags: join, entity-framework-core

```
public class accounts
{
    [Key]
    [StringLength(80)]
    public string account_id { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string firstname { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string lastname { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string email { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string department { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public DateTime lastmodified { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
}

public class roles
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public long role_id { get; set; } = 0;

    [StringLength(80)]
    public string role_name { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public DateTime lastmodified { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
}

//[Keyless]
public class relations
{
    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("roles")]
    public long role_id { get; set; } = 0;

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("accounts")]
    [StringLength(80)]
    public string account_id { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public DateTime lastmodified { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
}
```

How do I join accounts and roles in EF Core 6 in my controller (C# Blazor)? I have no clue how to write that down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
from a in db.accounts
from ro in db.roles
from r in db.relations
where a.account_id == r.account_id && r.role_id == ro.role_id
select ...
```

Comment: That's not EF core / blazor. It must look somewhat similar to this: https://entityframework.net/joining

Comment: Why is that?  The linq statements are powerful and easy-to-use. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/from-clause#using-multiple-from-clauses-to-perform-joins

Comment: Oh, I didn't understand this was linq. I am pretty new to EF core and have never been using linq so far.

Comment: Thx. Together with some info from the inet I figured how to do what I need.

Comment: I see. By the way, it is recommended to use Pascal case for class names and property names. And for a model class, we usually use singular form, e.g. `Account`. Besides, a `long` property has a default value of `0`, so you don't have to use `= 0;`.

Comment: I do so too; but the identifers are coming from an external customer spec, so I have no choice.